# Firebase retrieve data by filter array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from Posts Table by Post Key String Array. I saved the Post Key in another table like this.
[image: Post Key] 
I want to retrieve only these key from post table.

[image: This is posts Table]

My Problem is i don't want to make a lot of request by using looping like this

```
let postKey : [String] = ["-KMTThEk7HCmyFEilpGg", "-KMTbBsAIwTCAHJkskjz", "-KMTegDMI9QON7-0k2xA"]
        for key in postKey{
            DataService.ds.POST_REF.child(key).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
                print(snapshot)
            })
        }
```

Firebase *queryEqualToValue* can use only one key.
How can i retrieve this data by one request with PostKey Array?

Comment: you want all key value pair from posts?????

Comment: I want only specific key value pair by filtering postKey array from posts.